# Recurring payment not working with PayPal button in braintree

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing, braintree

I am using a PayPal button in my HTML Form. All works fine like PayPal ask for authentication and inject the payment_method_nonce in HTML form.

But, When i creating a subscription with this payment_method_nonce then its give me error that:-
Message:- Payment method token is invalid
Code:- 91903

I am using PHP Library and Here is my code snippet:-

```
$subscription = Braintree_Subscription::create(array(
    'paymentMethodToken' => payment_method_nonce that PayPal button inject in my form,
    'planId' => planId that created in Braintree,   
));
```

or if i use sale method using same payment_method_nonce like this:-

```
$subscription = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'amount' => $amount,
    'paymentMethodToken' => payment_method_nonce that PayPal button inject in my form
));
```

than its works fine.

Please let me know what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. You can always get in touch with [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you need more help.</sub>

Payment methods need to be [vaulted](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server/customer-management/create#customer-with-a-payment-method) before they can be used to [create a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/server/recurring-billing/create).

In the case of a nonce that doesn't point to a vaulted payment method, you can use it to create one, and then use that to create the subscription. (We'll update the docs to make this more clear.)

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $payment_method_nonce,
));

$token = $result->customer->paypalAccounts[0]->token;

$result = Braintree_Subscription::create(array(
  'paymentMethodToken' => $token,
  'planId' => 'planId that created in Braintree',
));
```

Comment: hell @afg I also used your above code it is working fine with my localhost but when I execute the same code in my server not returning any success response. when I checked my braintree account transaction is successfully done, what is the issue? Please help

Comment: @AmitKumarSahu Sorry, that's really not enough information to help you with your problem. Please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: this saved me a bunch of time. Note - 3 years later and the docs have yet be to updated! :P